# R: Velocity/Aggregation - excess unique counts of column B per column A within certain time periods?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, aggregate, aggregation

I'm exploring ways to identify when a count exceeds a certain threshold within a certain time period.

For example, let's say we have 4 columns - Transaction, Time, Email and CC. Throughout the data set, we want to identify WHICH user emails (Email) are involved with more than 2 credit cards (CC) within ANY 60 minute period.  Ideally, we would also like to know at WHAT (Transaction) this threshold is broken.

The end goal is to know something like this -

'CBC' used its 3rd (CC) in <= 60 minutes at 'Transaction' 50.

Simulated data:

```
library(stringi)
set.seed(123)
CC <- sample(1000:1199, 100, replace = TRUE)
Email <- stri_rand_strings(100, 3, pattern = "[A-D]")
Time <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00") + sort(sample(1:10000, 100))
DF <- data.frame(Time, Email, CC) 
DF <- tibble::rowid_to_column(DF, "Transaction")
              
> head(DF)
  Transaction                Time Email   CC
1           1 2020-01-01 00:00:05   CBB 1057
2           2 2020-01-01 00:04:40   DBD 1157
3           3 2020-01-01 00:08:11   DCB 1081
4           4 2020-01-01 00:09:39   ADB 1176
5           5 2020-01-01 00:11:39   ADC 1188
6           6 2020-01-01 00:13:45   ACD 1009
```

This seems to be a pretty unique question, as I'm essentially checking for excess/risky aggregation/counts throughout a data set.

An early dplyr attempt to set this up is as follows -

```
Counts_DF <- DF %>%
  group_by(Email)  %>%
  mutate(HourInter = cut(Time, breaks = "60 min"))   %>%
  group_by(Email, HourInter)  %>%
  summarize(Diff_Cards = n_distinct(CC)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Diff_Cards)) %>%
  filter(Diff_Cards > 2)

> head(Counts_DF)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Email [5]
  Email HourInter           Diff_Cards
  <fct> <chr>                    <int>
1 ABB   2020-01-01 01:22:00          3
2 BAC   2020-01-01 00:54:00          3
3 CAB   2020-01-01 00:35:00          3
4 CBC   2020-01-01 00:14:00          3
5 DAB   2020-01-01 01:41:00          3
```

However, I'm unsure what the 'HourInter' column is really doing and there is clearly no (Transaction) info available.

I've seen other questions for aggregations under static time intervals for just one column, but this is clearly a bit different. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table`-approach

```
library( data.table )
#make DF a data.table, set keys for optmised joining
setDT( DF, key = c("Email", "Time" ) )
#get CC used in hour window, and number of unique CC used last hour, by Email by row
DF[ DF, 
    #get desired values, suppress immediate output using {}
    c( "cc_last_hour", "unique_cc_last_hour" ) := {
      #temporary subset, with all DF values with the same Email, from the last hour
      val = DF[ Email == i.Email & 
                  Time %between% c( i.Time - lubridate::hours(1), i.Time) ]$CC
      #get values
      list( paste0( val, collapse = "-" ),
            uniqueN( val ) )
    }, 
    #do the above for each row
    by = .EACHI ]

#now subset rows where `unique_cc_used_last_hour` exceeds 2
DF[ unique_cc_last_hour > 2, ]

#    Transaction                Time Email   CC        cc_last_hour unique_cc_last_hour
# 1:          66 2020-01-01 01:35:32   AAD 1199      1152-1020-1199                   3
# 2:          78 2020-01-01 02:00:16   AAD 1152 1152-1020-1199-1152                   3
# 3:          53 2020-01-01 01:24:46   BAA 1096      1080-1140-1096                   3
# 4:          87 2020-01-01 02:15:24   BAA 1029      1140-1096-1029                   3
# 5:          90 2020-01-01 02:19:30   BAA 1120      1096-1029-1120                   3
# 6:          33 2020-01-01 00:55:52   BBC 1031      1196-1169-1031                   3
# 7:          64 2020-01-01 01:34:58   BDD 1093      1154-1052-1093                   3
# 8:          68 2020-01-01 01:40:07   CBC 1085      1022-1052-1085                   3
# 9:          38 2020-01-01 01:03:34   CCA 1073      1090-1142-1073                   3
#10:          21 2020-01-01 00:35:54   DBB 1025      1194-1042-1025                   3
#11:          91 2020-01-01 02:20:33   DDA 1109      1115-1024-1109                   3
```

## update based on OP's comment below

first, create some sample data with a transaction amount

```
#sample data with an added Amount
library(stringi)
set.seed(123)
CC <- sample(1000:1199, 100, replace = TRUE)
Email <- stri_rand_strings(100, 3, pattern = "[A-D]")
Time <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00") + sort(sample(1:10000, 100))
Amount <- sample( 50:100, 100, replace = TRUE )
DF <- data.frame(Time, Email, CC, Amount) 
DF <- tibble::rowid_to_column(DF, "Transaction")
```

here is the code to also calculate the sum of Amount, for the past hour.
A bit more explanation of the functionality of the code

1. make DF a data.table
2. 'loop' over each row of DF
3. for each row, take the Email and Time of that row and...
4. ... create a temporary subset of DF, where the Email is the same, and the Time is bewteen Time - 1 hour and Time
5. join on this this subset, creating new columns "cc_hr", "un_cc_hr" and "am_hr", which get their values from a list. So `paste0( val$CC, collapse = "-" )` fills the first column (i.e. "cc_hr"), `uniqueN( val$CC )` filles the second col (i.e. "un_cc_hr") and the sum of the amount ("am_hr") gets calculated by `sum( val$Amount )`.

As you can see, it does not calculate the score for every 60 minute interval, but in stead is defines the end of an interval based on the Time of a Transaction, and then looks for Transactions with the same Email within the hour before Time.
I assumed this is the behaviour you are looking for, and you're not interested in periods where nothing happens.

```
library( data.table )
#make DF a data.table, set keys for optmised joining
setDT( DF, key = c("Email", "Time" ) )
#self join
DF[ DF, 
    #get desired values, suppress immediate output using {}
    c( "cc_hr", "un_cc_hr", "am_hr" ) := {
      #create a temporary subset of DF, named val, 
      #   with all DF's rows with the same Email, from the last hour
      val = DF[ Email == i.Email & 
                  Time %between% c( i.Time - lubridate::hours(1), i.Time) ]
      #get values
      list( paste0( val$CC, collapse = "-" ),
            uniqueN( val$CC ),
            sum( val$Amount ) )  # <-- calculate the amount of all transactions 
    }, 
    #do the above for each row of DF
    by = .EACHI ]
```

**sample output**

```
#find all Transactions where, in the past hour,
#   1. the number of unique CC used > 2, OR 
#   2. the total amount paid > 180

DF[ un_cc_hr > 2 | am_hr > 180, ]
#     Transaction                Time Email   CC Amount               cc_hr un_cc_hr am_hr
#  1:          80 2020-01-01 02:03:05   AAB 1021     94           1089-1021        2   194
#  2:          66 2020-01-01 01:35:32   AAD 1199     60      1152-1020-1199        3   209
#  3:          78 2020-01-01 02:00:16   AAD 1152     63 1152-1020-1199-1152        3   272
#  4:          27 2020-01-01 00:40:50   BAA 1080    100           1169-1080        2   186
#  5:          53 2020-01-01 01:24:46   BAA 1096    100      1080-1140-1096        3   259
#  6:          87 2020-01-01 02:15:24   BAA 1029     71      1140-1096-1029        3   230
#  7:          90 2020-01-01 02:19:30   BAA 1120     93      1096-1029-1120        3   264
#  8:          33 2020-01-01 00:55:52   BBC 1031     55      1196-1169-1031        3   171
#  9:          64 2020-01-01 01:34:58   BDD 1093     78      1154-1052-1093        3   212
# 10:          42 2020-01-01 01:08:04   CBC 1052     96           1022-1052        2   194
# 11:          68 2020-01-01 01:40:07   CBC 1085    100      1022-1052-1085        3   294
# 12:          38 2020-01-01 01:03:34   CCA 1073     81      1090-1142-1073        3   226
# 13:          98 2020-01-01 02:40:40   CCC 1121     86           1158-1121        2   183
# 14:          21 2020-01-01 00:35:54   DBB 1025     67      1194-1042-1025        3   212
# 15:          91 2020-01-01 02:20:33   DDA 1109     99      1115-1024-1109        3   236
```

Comment: As a follow-up to this, what if we got rid of the (CC) column and replaced that with an (Amount) column. Then, let's say I wanted to identify when a certain dollar threshold (Amount) were broken under the same (Email) in a certain time period. So, very similar idea, except now we'd be summing in a column instead of counting unique values.  For example - let's say we want to identify WHICH user emails (Email) are involved with more than $150 (Amount) within ANY 60 minute period.  I'm playing around with your code to set this up, but am a little stuck. Thanks!

Comment: this is also possible, with some tinkering on the code... see updated answer above. I also included some more comments and explanation about the code.. When you keep in mind that you are 'looping' the rows of DF, working on a temporaty subset (based on values in the current row) and are performing calculations on this subset, the code will probably/hopefulle come to life ;-)

Comment: Great explanation, it looks and works great! I'll know if this validates with production data in about a week!

Answer (score 0):

You could always make the problem a bit easier by extracting the date and hour feature:

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123)
CC <- sample(1000:1199, 100, replace = TRUE)
Email <- stri_rand_strings(100, 3, pattern = "[A-D]")
Time <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00") + sort(sample(1:10000, 100))
DF <- data.frame(Time, Email, CC) 
DF <- tibble::rowid_to_column(DF, "Transaction")

DF %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Time),
         Hour = hour(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Hour, Email) %>% 
  summarise(Diff_Cards = n_distinct(CC)) %>% 
  filter(Diff_Cards > 2) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Diff_Cards))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on extracting date and hour!